# Как остановить цикл и продолжить его после нажатия пользователя продолжить Python

Tags: python, циклы

Есть цикл

```
i = 1
While i < 10:
    i += 1
```

К примеру, цикл дошёл до 5 и нужно вывести кнопку продолжить, если пользователь нажал продолжить продолжает цикл,6,7,8…
Возможно ли такое реализовать ?

Comment: да, простым `if i=5: input ()` (две строки) можно добиться даже без кнопок.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 1
while i < 10:
    if i == 5:
        input('Нажми ENTER чтобы продолжить')
    i += 1
```

Если `i == 5`, выводится сообщение "`Нажми ENTER чтобы продолжить`", чтобы продолжить нужно нажать `ENTER`.
И, кстати, `while`, да и вообще все ключевые слова `Python`, нужно писать с маленькой буквы.
**Совет:** почитайте `PEP-8`, он есть на русском.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, хорошо, обязательно ознакомлюсь с PEP-8